# IPython import local file

Tags: python, ipython, python-import

I've come across a weird disparity between IPython and the default python interpreter. I have a python file that shadows a built-in module's name: logging.py. Say it has a simple method foo().

If I start up the default python interpreter and call `import logging` it imports the local file and I can access `logging.foo()`.

If I start up IPython and call `import logging` it imports the python built-in module. If I change the name to a non-shadow (e.g. `import my_logging`) then the import will work as expected.

Which is the expected behaviour? The current directory is at the start of `sys.path` for both interpreters but they differ in which imports have priority.

Comment: I can confirm the same happens to me with Python3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import sys
print(sys.modules)
```

IPython starts with most of the standard library imported, including logging. Those modules seem to be imported by full path.

Speculation: IPython already imported those libraries by full path for internal use, now when you `import logging` again it checks that the module is already imported, regardless of the path, and does nothing.